# Send content of memory pointed by an IntPtr into a MemoryStream variable on C#

Tags: c#, memorystream, intptr

Im new to this languaje.

I think the question is very clear, i have an intptr received after calling a dll function and need to save the buffer that it points to into a MemoryStream variable. 
¿how do i do it ?

Comment: What did you try? What problems or issues did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the UnamangedMemoryStream instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx

Comment: oh, this helped! and it seems better. also the sample i found there showed me that i can initialize it using constructors. thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, please mark the answer as answered if it did, indeed answer your question. :)

Comment: i tryed, but i dont have enought reputation. i will once i have it. thanks.

Comment: I didn't know that you need a reputation to accept answers :) You tried clicking the check mark below the down arrow and it told you that?

Comment: Clear case of an AccessViolationException.